# lualatex texlive 2016 tcolorbox

Tags: luatex, tcolorbox, texlive-2016

If you compile with tl2016 lualatex this MWE

```
    \documentclass[10pt, xcolor=svgnames, x11names,  t]{beamer} 

    \usepackage{etoolbox}
    \usepackage{ifluatex}

\ifluatex
    \usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
    \usepackage[EU2]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{lualatex-math}
\else
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\fi

    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \usepackage{amsfonts}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{bm}
\ifluatex
    \setsansfont[Ligatures=TeX,
    ItalicFont={MyriadPro-SemiCnIt.otf},
    BoldFont={MyriadPro-BoldSemiCn.otf},
    BoldItalicFont={MyriadPro-BoldSemiCnIt.otf},
    SmallCapsFont={Delicious-SmallCaps.otf}
    ]{MyriadPro-SemiCn.otf}                                 

\else
    \usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
    \usepackage[condensed, scale]{tgheros}
\fi 
\normalfont

\usepackage[listings,theorems,skins, raster, breakable]{tcolorbox}

\ifluatex
\newtcblisting{mydocument}{%
  left skip=-4.2pt,width=1.01\linewidth, sharp corners,%
  beforeafter skip=0.5\baselineskip,%
  leftlower=0pt,rightlower=0pt,%
  lower separated=false,middle=0pt,%
  colframe=blue, enhanced, %
  interior style={top color=yellow!5!white,bottom color=yellow!5!white},%
  righthand width=4cm,halign=left,%
  pdf comment,%
  listing side comment,%
  compilable listing,%
  run lualatex}
\else
\newtcblisting{mydocument}{%
  left skip=-4.2pt,width=1.01\linewidth, sharp corners,%
  beforeafter skip=0.5\baselineskip,%
  leftlower=0pt,rightlower=0pt,%
  lower separated=false,middle=0pt,%
  colframe=blue, enhanced, %
  interior style={top color=yellow!5!white,bottom color=yellow!5!white},%
  righthand width=4cm,halign=left,%
  pdf comment,%
  listing side comment,%
  compilable listing,%
  run pdflatex}
\fi


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]{TCB}
\begin{mydocument}
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
Hello%
world.

Hello
world.
\end{document}
\end{mydocument}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

you have this error:

```
    Package tcolorbox Error: PDF file `mwebeamersans-listin
g-1.pdf' not found.
```

The file name is mewbeamersans.tex. With pdflatex the compilation is ok. With TL2015 and lualatex also the compilation is ok. Any help?

Comment: As far as a I know: `\usepackage{luatex85}`

Comment: No, the error is the same after load `luatex85` package.

Comment: I compiled your document (after commenting the fonts) and it works out of the box with `lualatex`

Comment: Sorry. You need to delete all aux files (specially `mwebeamersans-listing-1.tex`file) before to compile with lualatex plus TL2016. I have tested again and I have the same error (after commenting the fonts)

Comment: You need `\usepackage{shellesc}`; however there are problems with `standalone` that I'm trying to isolate.

Comment: @jpayansomet: I've deleted all files now (except of the source `.tex` file, of course) and recompiled with `lualatex` again -- I got no error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's better to minimize the example.

The error appears also with

```
\documentclass[10pt, xcolor=svgnames, x11names,  t]{beamer} 

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage[listings,theorems,skins, raster, breakable]{tcolorbox}

\newtcblisting{mydocument}{%
  left skip=-4.2pt,width=1.01\linewidth, sharp corners,%
  beforeafter skip=0.5\baselineskip,%
  leftlower=0pt,rightlower=0pt,%
  lower separated=false,middle=0pt,%
  colframe=blue, enhanced, %
  interior style={top color=yellow!5!white,bottom color=yellow!5!white},%
  righthand width=4cm,halign=left,%
  pdf comment,%
  listing side comment,%
  compilable listing,%
  run lualatex}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]{TCB}
\begin{mydocument}
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
Hello%
world.

Hello
world.
\end{document}
\end{mydocument}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

if compiled with `lualatex -shell-escape`. You need to add `\usepackage{shellesc}`, but you also need some adjustment for `standalone`, because it has not been updated to take into consideration that `\pdfpagewidth` and `\pdfpageheight` have been renamed to `\pagewidth` and `\pageheight`.

This can be solved by using a file named `standalone.cfg` in the same directory as your main file containing

```
\ifdefined\pdfpagewidth
\else
  \let\pdfpagewidth\pagewidth
  \let\pdfpageheight\pageheight
\fi
```

You can produce it automatically if you use `filecontents`:

```
\begin{filecontents}{standalone.cfg}
\ifdefined\pdfpagewidth
\else
  \let\pdfpagewidth\pagewidth
  \let\pdfpageheight\pageheight
\fi
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[10pt, xcolor=svgnames, x11names,  t]{beamer} 

\usepackage{shellesc}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage[listings,theorems,skins, raster, breakable]{tcolorbox}

\newtcblisting{mydocument}{%
  left skip=-4.2pt,width=1.01\linewidth, sharp corners,%
  beforeafter skip=0.5\baselineskip,%
  leftlower=0pt,rightlower=0pt,%
  lower separated=false,middle=0pt,%
  colframe=blue, enhanced, %
  interior style={top color=yellow!5!white,bottom color=yellow!5!white},%
  righthand width=4cm,halign=left,%
  pdf comment,%
  listing side comment,%
  compilable listing,%
  run lualatex}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]{TCB}
\begin{mydocument}
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
Hello%
world.

Hello
world.
\end{document}
\end{mydocument}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

An alternative to writing `standalone.cfg` is to add

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
```

to the document you want to compile

```
\begin{mydocument}
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
Hello%
world.

Hello
world.
\end{document}
\end{mydocument}
```

Comment: Thanks egreg. But which is the reason that there is not any problem with TL2015?

Comment: @jpayansomet TL 2015 has LuaTeX 0.80, whereas TL 2016 has LuaTeX 0.95 that underwent several changes.

Comment: yes, I know. But it seems a new problem. I have checked the time compilation with LuaTeX 0.9 is less than LuaTeX 0.8. I suppose there will be a lot of benefits more, but...

Comment: This has already been reported https://bitbucket.org/martin_scharrer/standalone/issues/23/no-write18-or-pdfxxx-commands-in-luatex

Comment: @jpayansomet luatex is beta software and the maintainers do not try to maintain compatibility with older versions (or with tex) luatex has changed radically several commands being renamed, several being removed, and internal lua interfaces changing. Not all packages have been updated yet

Comment: `David Carlisle`and ègreg`I greatly appreciate the effort of maintainers. My intention is to debug and use the new version. I am convinced that it will be worth continuing to work on developing luatex.

Comment: With the corrections and addition the problem is solved. Thanks you

Comment: `David and Egreg`: unfortunately, when I have updated tcolorbox package, there is  new error. I think it is necessary to wait for some days.