# LuaLaTeX, TeXLive 2016, standalone: undefined control sequence

Tags: luatex, texlive, standalone, texlive-2016

Since I installed TeXLive 2016 I cannot build documents with the `standalone` document class any more using LuaLaTeX (PDFLaTeX works fine). For example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
hi
\end{document}
```

Gives me:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\sa@placebox ->\newpage \global \pdfpagewidth 
                                              =\wd \sa@box \global \pdfpageh...

l.4 \end{document}
```

How to fix that?

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/314429/4427 In this case, just add `\RequirePackage{luatex85}` as the very first line.

Comment: @egreg thanks, what to do with this question? Duplicate or remove?

Comment: Well, the other question is focused on a different topic. A CW answer will do.

Comment: see also https://bitbucket.org/martin_scharrer/standalone/issues/23/no-write18-or-pdfxxx-commands-in-luatex

Comment: The newest `standalone` version v1.3a 2018-03-26 fixes this problem.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

The fix is easy: add `\RequirePackage{luatex85}` as the very first line, a temporary workaround until `standalone` is updated. It should do no harm even after the update.

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
hi
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you foresee any issues if putting a `\usepackage{luatex85}` immediately *after* `\documentclass{standalone}`?  It does seem to work if I try it.

Comment: @Szabolcs This case may work, but others may not: it depends if the class code “uses”, say, `\pdfpagewidth`, instead of just storing it in a macro for later call. So, if a package/class performs computations based on `\pdfpagewidth` at loading time, they need `luatex85` having already done its work.

Comment: The newest `standalone` version v1.3a 2018-03-26 fixes this problem as it does not use `\pdfpagewidth` with LuaTeX anymore and also loads `luatex85` itself.

Answer (score 18):

The easiest way is to load `luatex85` package. You probably will need to load it before `documentclass`, using `RequirePackage`

The longer story is that luatex now no longer defines many primitives with `pdf` prefix. The `luatex85` package defines aliases of primitives which have the same names as in `pdftex` and earlier versions of `luatex`.