# Algorithmic graph drawing with TikZ & PGF

Tags: graphs, tikz-graphdrawing

I'm trying out the algorithmic graph drawing capabilities of TikZ/PGF and initially I was very exited. However, now I am stuck.

My example is below. I think the graph would look better if node "J" was moved down and left and node "G" was moved inside the cycle A-I-J-F-A.

So far I have tried different random seeds and different random orders of the lines in the TeX-file. I have also tried to use absolute node positioning that the force directed drawing would fine-tune, but it never produced anything.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{force}
\begin{document}
\tikz \graph [spring layout, random seed=1] {
  A -- F;
  A -- G;
  A -- I;
  B -- F;
  C -- D;
  C -- F;
  D -- E;
  D -- H;
  D -- I;
  E -- I;
  F -- J;
  G -- I;
  G -- J;
  I -- J;
};
\end{document}
```

[image: Simple graph]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Dummy question: if you know how your graph should look like, could manual positionning be an acceptable solution to you?

Comment: @ebo: Yes, manual positioning is how I currently do it. It has it's pros and cons. Perhaps a good solution would be to give an initial configuration manually and then let the computer smooth it out. I think the Tikz manual says you can do it, but I can't make it work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I see that you're using `spring layout` but it seems to me that the resulting graphic is more like distributed charges (electric charges) making me think that the `spring electrical layout` is more suiting. Just by using it you already see the difference in the final graph. Furthermore, to fine tune the graphic you can use the `nudge=<coordinate>` key (or the variants `nudge up`, `down`, `left` and `right`), although to mee it seems a little rudimentar, but if the drawing needs 'simple' nudges, than it's ok:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{force}
\begin{document}
\tikz \graph [spring electrical layout, random seed=1] {
  A -- F;
  A -- I;
  B -- F;
  C -- D;
  C -- F;
  D -- E;
  D -- H;
  D -- I;
  E -- I;
  F -- J[nudge=(210:10mm)];
  I -- J;
  G[nudge=(260:11mm)] -- J;
  G -- A;
  G -- I;
};
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can alse try to set `electric charge`s to the nodes, fine tunning the intensity they repell (positive values) or atract (negative values) the connected nodes. Though with this way the result is sometimes quite unpredictable.

### Second Approach

If you look at the previous drawing seems that node `J` has an invisible connection with nodes `C` and `D`. The same could be said for the node `G` with `F`. My thought was, if I could make this invisible connection then the resulting graph would probably be what the OP wants without any `nudge`s and with more reliable graph. To do so we must give the line-to operator (`--`) the option `draw=none` when making the Connections (I also took the liberty of shortening the code a little):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{force}
\begin{document}
\tikz \graph [spring electrical layout] {
  A -- F -- C -- D -- E -- I -- A;
  D -- I;
  B -- F;
  H -- D;
  I -- J -- F;
  I -- G -- A;
  G -- J;
  % invisible connections
  D --[draw=none] J --[draw=none] C;
  G --[draw=none] F;
};
\end{document}
```

The result is nearly the same as before, but should give no Errors this time:

[image]

Comment: For me, this example fails with `! Undefined control sequence.
\sa@placebox ->\newpage \global \pdfpagewidth<br>
                                              =\wd \sa@box \global \pdfpageh...
l.20 };`. I have LuaTeX, Version 0.95.0 (TeX Live 2016).

Comment: Well, that's just weird. Worked in Overleaf as well as in my PC with Windows 10/TL 2015. I have no idea if something changed from 2015 to 16, maybe it's a bug.

Comment: I had also tried `spring electrical layout` and `spring electrical layout'`. The results I got required more than a few nudges.

Comment: Hm, that's bad... But look, with Ti*k*Z's `graphdrawing` library you're supposed to not care *so much* about the position of everything, then a few nudges will always manage it. If you're requiring a lot of fine tuning maybe it's because you want a strict drawing and therefore are better off with manually positioned graph... Also, did you try setting `electric charge` values for the nodes? Maybe that also helps.

Comment: @Mankka, please test the second approach. I believe it's more elegant and should give no errors. `:D`

Comment: I'm sorry, same error with the second approach (on a different machine). Lualatex gives me: `! Undefined control sequence. \sa@placebox ->\newpage \global \pdfpagewidth` and pdflatex says `! Package pgf Error: You need to run LuaTeX to use the graph drawing library.`

Comment: @Mankka, it appers to be an incompatibilty between LuaLaTeX from TL2016 and the `standalone` class see here for the solution: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/315025/lualatex-texlive-2016-standalone-undefined-control-sequence though if you just copy the tikz code to your project, it should be working, provided that the packages and libraries are properly loaded.