# Minimizing the number of nested loops in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

The black points in the picture form the letter A. It is created with using for loop only. \ifnum doesn't allow two or more conditions. So I draw the desire result using five nest for loop. It is an inefficient way to do so...Is there a better way to do so?

[image]

Here is the code:

```
 \documentclass{article}

 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usepackage{amssymb}
 \usepackage{xifthen}

 \begin{document}

 \begin{figure}

   \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]

      \foreach \x in {0,...,11}
         \foreach \y in {0,...,14}
           {
             \draw (\x,\y) circle(2pt); 
           }

     \foreach \x in {1,...,3}
         \foreach \y in {1,...,11}
            {
              \fill (\x,\y) circle(2pt);              
            }

     \foreach \x in {8,...,10}
        \foreach \y in {1,...,11}
           {
             \fill (\x,\y) circle(2pt);              
           }

     \foreach \x in {4,...,8}
        \foreach \y in {4,...,6}
          {
             \fill (\x,\y) circle(2pt);              
          }

     \foreach \x in {4,...,8}
       \foreach \y in {9,...,11}
            {
              \fill (\x,\y) circle(2pt);              
            }

   \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{figure}
  \end{document}
```

Comment: You can nest `\ifnum ... \fi`, though, to combine conditions.

Answer (score 13):

You can punch through instead.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\clip[postaction=draw] foreach\x in{0,...,11}{\foreach\y in{0,...,14}{(\x,\y)circle(2pt)}};
\fill[even odd rule] (0.5,0.5) |- (10.5,11.5) |- (7.5,0.5) |- (3.5,3.5) |- (0.5,0.5) 
                     (3.5,6.5) rectangle (7.5,8.5) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is genius.

Answer (score 5):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \x in {0,...,11}
  {
    \foreach \y [evaluate=\y as \s using  {((\y==0)||(\y>11)) ? "" : ( ( (((\x>0)&&(\x<4))||(\x>7)&&(\x<11)) || ( ( (\x>3)&&(\x<9) ) && ( ( (\y>3)&&(\y<7) ) ||  (\y>8) ) ) ) ? "fill" : "" )  }  ] in {0,...,14}
    {
      \draw [\s] (\x,\y) circle(2pt);
    }
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: dotted 'A']

Answer (score 5):

With luaLaTeX.

For using standalone class, [I still need this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/315027/116936)

### The output

[image]

### The code

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode*}
  function a(i,j)
    middle = (j > 4 and j < 9) and (i>11 or i==7 or i==8)
    square = (i < 15) and (i > 3) and (j>1) and (j<12) 
    return square and not middle
  end

  function drawOrFill(i,j,letter)
    tex.print(letter(i,j) and [=[\fill[blue]]=] or [[\draw]])
  end
\end{luacode*}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \i in {1,...,15}
  {
    \foreach \j in {1,...,12}
    {
      \directlua{drawOrFill(\i,\j,a)} (\j,-\i) circle (4pt);
    }
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```