# Plotting a curve using Lualatex within Standalone environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, pdftex, luatex, standalone

I am trying to plot a curve as shown below:

```
%&lualatex
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
    \addplot [red] {-sqrt(x^3+7)};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The problem is that the solution works pretty well in `pdflatex`, however, when I try to compile this `MWE` (given in the answer) with `lualatex`, I get a series of errors like:

```
> ! Undefined control sequence. \sa@placebox ->\newpage \global
> \pdfpagewidth 
>                                               =\wd \sa@box \global \pdfpageh... l.13 \end{document}
>                   The control sequence at the end of the top line of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have misspelled it (e.g.,
> `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct spelling (e.g., `I\hbox').
> Otherwise just continue, and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
> 
> ! You can't use a prefix with `the character ='. <to be read again> 
> = l.13 \end{document}
>                   I'll pretend you didn't say \long or \outer or \global or \protected.
> 
> ! Missing number, treated as zero. <to be read again>  \global  l.13
> \end{document}
>                   A number should have been here; I inserted `0'. (If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number, look up `weird
> error' in the index to The TeXbook.)
> 
> ! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). <to be read again>  \global 
> l.13 \end{document}
>                   Dimensions can be in units of em, ex, in, pt, pc, cm, mm, dd, cc, nd, nc, bp, or sp; but yours is a new one! I'll assume
> that you meant to say pt, for printer's points. To recover gracefully
> from this error, it's best to delete the erroneous units; e.g., type
> `2' to delete two letters. (See Chapter 27 of The TeXbook.)
> 
> ! Undefined control sequence. \sa@placebox ...wd \sa@box \global
> \pdfpageheight 
>                                                   =\ht \sa@box \global \pape... l.13 \end{document}
>                   The control sequence at the end of the top line of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have misspelled it (e.g.,
> `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct spelling (e.g., `I\hbox').
> Otherwise just continue, and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
> 
> ! You can't use a prefix with `the character ='. <to be read again> 
> = l.13 \end{document}
>                   I'll pretend you didn't say \long or \outer or \global or \protected.
> 
> ! Missing number, treated as zero. <to be read again>  \global  l.13
> \end{document}
>                   A number should have been here; I inserted `0'. (If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number, look up `weird
> error' in the index to The TeXbook.)
> 
> ! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). <to be read again>  \global 
> l.13 \end{document}
>                   Dimensions can be in units of em, ex, in, pt, pc, cm, mm, dd, cc, nd, nc, bp, or sp; but yours is a new one! I'll assume
> that you meant to say pt, for printer's points. To recover gracefully
> from this error, it's best to delete the erroneous units; e.g., type
> `2' to delete two letters. (See Chapter 27 of The TeXbook.)
> 
> 
> Overfull \hbox (30.56pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 13--13
> []\TU/lmr/m/n/10 ==[]   []
```

Could anyone tell me where it is going wrong?

> Disclaimer: I am using the `MikTex-2.9.6300` and `standalone` was packaged on `21-Jul-2015`.

Comment: Works for me with TexLive 2018. Doesn't work with TexLive 2016. After adding `\RequirePackage{luatex85}` at the very beginning (before `\documentclass` it became working for 2016 as well. Hopefully, someone can explain that.

Comment: @SergeiGolovan Thanks for the information, I am using MikTex (probably the not-so-old version). I will update my tag accordingly.

Comment: "not-so-old" is probably not enough. standalone was updated only a few month ago if I remember correctly.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Updated my question.

Comment: relevant is not the version of miktex but of the standalone class. But beside this: MikTex-2.9.6300 is rather old.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Updated both of the info in the question.

Comment: I think my edit interfered. But do you really need a confirmation that a package from 2015 could be a bit old?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message indicates that your standalone package is outdated. So run in the miktex console (admin and user mode) the update tool.

If you don't want to update use this https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/315027/2388.