# Standalone in Lualatex: `luatex85.sty' no more found

Tags: luatex, standalone

In LuaTeX, Version 1.0.4 (TeX Live 2017/Debian), in order to use the standalone mode,  I needed to add `\RequirePackage{luatex85}`, as in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/315027/227733). This method is called there *a temporary workaround until standalone is updated*. Now I upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS, which comes with LuaTeX, Version 1.10.0 (TeX Live 2019/Debian), and `luatex85` can no more be found:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `luatex85.sty' not found.
```

but `standalone` still does not work without it. In other words, this example

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

does not compile, no matter if the line `\RequirePackage{luatex85}` is present or not. The error message is as above in both cases.

I copied `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/luatex85` from one distribution to another, it did not help. Can I somehow fix the problem?

Comment: luatex85.sty still exist but it looks as if you didn't install everything. check if there are more tex related packages that you can install.

Comment: you should not copy files by hand in to texmf-dist as that will confuse your package manager, but if you do, you need to run `sudo mktexlsr` afterwards to update its file lists

Comment: I installed `texlive-latex-base` and even `texlive-latex-extra`. Anyways, `sudo mktexlsr` works, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install luatex, for example via texlive on ubuntu etc :

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-luatex
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).